# Ajax form submit twice or once but missing last value no submit button

Tags: jquery

It may seems to be asked a few time, yet I can't find a solution.

```
<form id="foo">    
    <div class="g1">
     <input type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="1">
     <input type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="2">
     <input type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="g2">
     <input type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="1">
     <input type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="5">
     <input type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="g3">
     <input type="radio" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="6">
     <input type="radio" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="5">
     <input type="radio" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="3">
    </div>
 </form>
```

That is a basic of my actual code but same concept, **g2** and **g3** are hidden, when a user select one option from g1 it shows the next block, user selects from **g2** and it shows **g3**...
When user select one option from the group **g3** it submit the form via ajax.
The problem is that it submits the form twice the first time only send options 1 and 2, and the second time it send's the whole form.
if I use `event.preventDefault();` it only submit the form once which is what I want the problem is that is not sending the value of `op3`

```
$('[data-send]').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
var formdata = $('form#foo').serialize();
// next is a regular ajax, post, dataType: 'json'... etc
})
```

So, by using `event.preventDefault();` it doesn't send my last radio value and if I don't, it submits the form twice, if I use `return false;`, result is the same as `preventDefault();`,

Comment: `$('form@foo').serialize();` ?  it seems to be `$('#foo').serialize();`

Comment: @AlivetoDie correct, I made a mistake while typing the example...

Comment: @AlivetoDie, G1 is not hidden, when you select from G1 it shows G2, when you select from G2 it shows G3 and at that point it not hidden any more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('[data-send]')` will not be rcognisable, so add class to `g3` radio buttons and use that class for click

Code:-

```
$('.submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var formdata = $('form#foo').serialize();
})
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$('.submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var formdata = $('form#foo').serialize();
   console.log(formdata);
   //or you can use below too
   //var formdata1 = $('form#foo').serializeArray();
   //console.log(formdata);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="foo">    
    <div class="g1">
     <input type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="1">
     <input type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="2">
     <input type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="g2">
     <input type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="1">
     <input type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="5">
     <input type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="g3">
     <input type="radio" class="submit-form" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="6">
     <input type="radio" class="submit-form" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="5">
     <input type="radio" class="submit-form" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="3">
    </div>
 </form>
```

***Note:***- instead of `op1[], op2[],op3[]` you can use `op[1],op[2],op[3]` or best is `op[]` only. It will make indexes itself. (0=> first div radio buttons,1=>2nd div radio buttons etc)

Comment: I think that was the problem using data, it is an inherited project, 10 dynamic forms, first form worked fine it only has radios and each is selected by hand, the other 9 forms have radios and check boxes, but didn't worked, now by changing the data to a class trigger it worked fine!.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add some class attribute in your code as per below:

```
<form id="foo">    
    <div class="g1">
     <input class="radio_g1" type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="1">
     <input class="radio_g1" type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="2">
     <input class="radio_g1" type="radio" data-next="2" name="op1[]" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="g2" style="display: none;">
     <input class="radio_g2" type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="1">
     <input class="radio_g2" type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="5">
     <input class="radio_g2" type="radio" data-next="3" name="op2[]" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="g3" style="display: none;">
     <input class="radio_g3" type="radio" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="6">
     <input class="radio_g3" type="radio" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="5">
     <input class="radio_g3" type="radio" data-send="1" name="op3[]" value="3">
    </div>
 </form>
```

In js code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.radio_g1', function(){
    $(document).find('.g2').show();
});

$(document).on('change', '.radio_g2', function(){
    $(document).find('.g3').show();
});

$(document).on('change', '.radio_g3', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $(document).find('#foo').serializeArray();                   
    console.log(formdata);
});
```

result like:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "op1[]", value: "2"}
1: {name: "op2[]", value: "3"}
2: {name: "op3[]", value: "5"}
length: 3
```

Comment: If I use an extra input or button for submit then the current jQuery ajax works fine, the main I idea is not to use an extra click but the one already in there... but thanks.

Comment: Result seems the same on my end, either submit the form twice or missing the last option.